# Can function inputs be seen by others?

Tags: solidity

Sorry if this is a basic question. I'm learning solidity via implementing a basic game where users have to enter a choice and a passcode (as a nonce),

```
function addPlayer(Choice _choice, uint256 passcode) public payable {           
Players[playerNum] = Player(msg.sender,keccak256(abi.encode(passcode,_choice,msg.sender)),Choice.Nothing);
```

But when  someone enters their choice and passcode, we can see it in the decoded input in remix:
[image]

So can someone else see this data and is this a valid way to implement a commit-reveal scheme? Or does the user have to hash their choice somewhere else, then input the hash instead?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, others can decode the data as well. No matter what product you use to store passwords, the process is always similar. No password should be stored as is. It should be hashed. However in your case, The blockchain is public, therefore the hash of the password would be visible to anyone.

You should reconsider the use of password. You can trust that msg.sender is the account calling your contract. Maybe just add a registration process instead of a password.

```
mapping (address => bool) public registered_user;

// on registration
registered_user[msg.sender] = true;

// on access 
require(registered_user[msg.sender],'Not registered');

// unregister 
registered_user[msg.sender] = false;
```

This way you have a way of controlling access. You could even go further and use the openZeppelin AccessControl contract.